# d3 Text and line breaking

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to create the below chart based on the data sets I have. Below is the sample code I have created so far. Date is hard coded as of now. Is it possible to help how to create the expected output.

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lR27.jpg)

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXTBA.jpg)

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Bar Chart</title>  
 </head>
 <style>

 body {
   font: 15px sans-serif;
   shape-rendering: crispEdges;
 }
 
 svg {
   fill: #ffbfbf;
  }

 .day {
   fill: #fff;
   stroke: #ccc;
 }

 .month {
   fill: none;
   stroke: #000;
   stroke-width: 2px;
 }

 .RdYlGn .q0-11{fill:rgb(165,0,38)}
 .RdYlGn .q1-11{fill:rgb(215,48,39)}
 .RdYlGn .q2-11{fill:rgb(244,109,67)}
 .RdYlGn .q3-11{fill:rgb(253,174,97)}
 .RdYlGn .q4-11{fill:rgb(254,224,139)}
 .RdYlGn .q5-11{fill:rgb(255,255,191)}
 .RdYlGn .q6-11{fill:rgb(217,239,139)}
 .RdYlGn .q7-11{fill:#ffdfbf}
 .RdYlGn .q8-11{fill:#bfffdf}
 .RdYlGn .q9-11{fill:rgb(26,152,80)}
 .RdYlGn .q10-11{fill:rgb(0,104,55)}

 </style>
 <body>
 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.js"> </script>
 
  <h3>Try & Buy Model: </h3>
  
 <script>

  //Array of dummy data values (simple!)
  //var dataset = [ 5, 10, 13, 18, 20, 25, 30, 40, 50];
  
  d3.csv("test.csv", function(error, csv) {
     if (error) throw error;

  var data = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.Date_Time; })
    .rollup(function(d) { return (d[0].leadtoOI); })
    .map(csv);
    
  var width = 1000,
   height = 40,
   cellSize = 17; // cell size
   padding = 10;
  
  var percent = d3.format(".1%"),
   dformat = d3.time.format("%y-%m-%d").parse;
  
  //Configure x and y scale functions
  //Note each scale accounts for padding
  var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(csv)])
      .range([0, width]);

  //Note y scale inverts values, so larger inputs return smaller
  //outputs.  That's because we want the y value for the "top" 
  //of each bar.  You could flip the two range values to take
  //the opposite approach.
  var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([ 0, d3.max(csv) ])
      .rangeRound([ height - padding, padding ]);
  
  var color = d3.scale.quantize()
    .domain([0, 1])
    .range(d3.range(11).map(function(d) { return "q" + d + "-11"; }));
 
  //var color = d3.scale.category20c();  
 
  //Configure y axis generator
  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(yScale)
      .orient("left")
      .ticks(5);
      
  var svg = d3.select("body")
     .data(d3.range(2005, 2010))
     .append("svg")
     .attr("width", width)
     .attr("height", height)
     .attr("class", "RdYlGn")
     .append("g");
     //.attr("transform", "translate(" + ((width - cellSize * 53) / 2) + "," + (height - cellSize * 7 - 1) + ")");;

  svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", 10)
    .attr("y", 10)
    .attr("font-size", "12px")
    .style("fill", "black")
    //.text("2015-11-11")
    //.text("x", x(csv[0])
    //.text(function (d) {
    //    //alert(d.Date_Time);
    //    //alert(d3.time.format("%y-%m-%d"));
    //    //alert(dformat(d.Date_Time));
    //    return d.Date_Time; 
    //  })  
    //.attr("transform", "translate(10,5)");
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (cellSize + 2.5 ) + ")")
    
  //d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse    
  
  //Create bars
  var rects = svg.selectAll("rect")
       .data(csv)
       .enter()
       .append("rect")
       .attr("x", function (d, i) { return (cellSize + (cellSize * i ) + i); })
       .attr("y", cellSize)
       .attr("width", cellSize)
       .attr("height", cellSize)
       .attr("fill", function(d) { if (d.leadtoOI == 1 ) { 
              return "#ff6666"; 
              }
              return "#ccff99";
        })  
     //.attr("fill", function (d) {return color (d) ; })
       .attr("transform", "translate(" + (cellSize + 100 ) + ", 0)");
       
  rects.append("title")
    .text(function(d) { return d.Date_Time+ "-" + d.leadtoOI; });
      
   });
     
    
  
 </script>
```

**data.csv**

```
Date_Time,leadtoOI,OI Prediction from Model
2010-11-11,0,0
2010-11-11,0,0
2010-11-11,0,0
2010-11-11,1,0
2010-11-11,0,0
2010-11-11,0,0
2010-11-11,0,0
2010-11-11,0,0
2010-11-11,0,0
2010-11-11,0,0
2010-11-11,0,0
2010-11-11,0,0
2010-11-11,0,0
2010-11-11,0,0
2010-11-11,0,0
2010-11-11,0,0
2010-11-11,0,0
2010-11-11,0,0
2010-11-11,0,0
2010-11-11,0,0
2010-11-11,0,0
2010-11-11,0,0
2010-11-11,0,0
2010-11-11,0,0
2010-11-11,0,0
2010-11-11,0,0
2010-11-11,0,0
2010-11-11,0,0
2010-11-11,0,0
2010-11-11,1,0
2010-11-11,0,0
2010-11-11,0,0
2010-11-12,0,0
2010-11-12,0,0
2010-11-12,0,0
2010-11-12,0,0
2010-11-12,0,0
```

Comment: you're code snippet doesnt run :/

Comment: The above code run if you are using python as local http server. It works